# Android Studio Preview changes once I add a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

On the right side of my Android Studio I can see a preview of my app on a selected device(currently Nexus 6p).  I see the outline of the phone and the screen.  But when I add a ScrollView to the xml layout, the phone disappears and just a white rectangle remains.  I can still see a preview on the white rectangle but I would like to see the phone and screen preview.  Is there any way to make that happen? I included a link of before and after. Note how the preview changes.

[Before ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPXOA.png)
[After ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNrq4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything inside a FrameLayout